# PageRequestManagerServerErrorException when __doPostBack from within jQuery event, but not from console?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, dopostback

For some reason, when trying to call __doPostBack to update my UpdatePanel from within a jQuery event, the page simply refreshes.

Delving deeper, when the following code is executed:

```
$('#modal-forgottenpassword .modal-close').live('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();   
    $('#modal-forgottenpassword input[type=hidden]').val('0');   
    __doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Body$buttonReset','');  
});
```

and looking at Firebug (or similar), I get the following just before the page refreshes:

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0
```

Yet, if I were to use the console in Chrome or Firebug and execute

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH_Body$buttonReset','');
```

It works fine.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't think it was "that" simple, I used a work around.

```
$('#CPH_Body_buttonReset').click();
```